# Execute a prepared statement in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have to run 40K requests against a username:

```
SELECT * from user WHERE login = :login
```

It's slow, so I figured I would just use a prepared statement.

So I do

```
e = sqlalchemy.create_engine(...)
c = e.connect()
c.execute("PREPARE userinfo(text) AS SELECT * from user WHERE login = $1")
r = c.execute("EXECUTE userinfo('bob')")
for x in r:
    do_foo()
```

But I have a:

```
InterfaceError: (InterfaceError) cursor already closed None None
```

I don't understand why I get an exception

Comment: Works for me. What version are you using, there was a slight change in cursor handling before 0.5 (r5236) that could have fixed this issue.

But even if it works, I highly doubt the parsing and planning overhead is big enough for it to really matter. Better batch things together as suggested below.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how to solve your cursor related error message, but I dont think a prepared staement will solve your performance issue - as long as your using SQL server 2005 or later the execution plan for `SELECT * from user WHERE login = $login` will already be re-used and there will be no performance gain from the prepared statement. I dont know about MySql or other SQL database servers, but I suspect they too have similar optimisations for Ad-Hoc queries that make the prepared statement redundant.

It sounds like the cause of the performance hit is more down to the fact that you are making 40,000 round trips to the database - you should try and rewrite the query so that you are only executing one SQL statement with a list of the login names. Am I right in thinking that MySql supports an aray data type? If it doesnt (or you are using Microsoft SQL) you should look into passing in some sort of delimited list of usernames.

Comment: I'm not in a web environment. It's a standalone application synchronizing an ldap directory with a postgresql database.
The request was just an example.
I also have requests with multiple joins and where clauses.
Would you think of a performance gain in that situation ?

Comment: Even if the database server is local (either locally on the network or even on the same physical machine) there will still be an overhead associated with each request, and for simple queries this overhead will be relatively large compared to the work needed to execute the actual query.
Other reasons to batch queries together is that it helps the database server optimise the queries better.

Answer (score 1):

From [this discussion](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlalchemy@googlegroups.com/msg08278.html), it might be a good idea to check your paster debug logs in case there is a better error message there.